# Unzip HTML Email Bodies from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I am in the process of migrating from a recruitment ATS called Bullhorn, who also acted as our mail server. We have been provided with a backup of our data which includes all our emails stored in a table - so far so good. However, each of those emails' bodies is stored in the database table as an `Image` type as a zipped binary (Not so helpful).

I'm pretty stumped with how to get this stuff out. There is a forum in which there is a thread dedicated to this but predictably Bullhorn are not so enthusiastic spending time supporting customers who are migrating away. Here is the thread: http://supportforums.bullhorn.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=1672

As I explain in that thread, I have used a program called Chilkat with which I can successfully read a table row, decompress the Email Body Column and display the raw HTML in the console window. But now, I don't really know where to go. I've read in to Datasets and Table Adapters but I'm not too sure how I can get the Chilkat software to work on data within that dataset.

So, I wonder if anyone can help out with this and provide some guidance?

Or.... I've been reading about using SQL to store binaries and it seems it has it's own compression - so could I use a CLR as a stored procedure to be able to give better access to this data.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to output this in to either a CSV file or use GeniusConnect to recreate an Outlook file - ultimately ending up in Gmail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(Originally posted not being logged in - added this to stop it being flagged as a duplicate)

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: [`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.

Comment: I do a lot of migration work (most one off stuff) and I am always writing small C# apps to handle sticky issues like this.